# Opencart minimum order price exclude one category

Tags: php, opencart

I am using opencart and successfully added minimum order price for all transactions.
This is the code I used:

```
<?php if ($this->cart->getSubtotal() >= 10) { ?>
<div id="payment"><?php echo $payment; ?></div>
<?php } else { ?>
<div class="warning">Minimum 10 Euro to checkout</div>
<?php }  ?>
```

Now I want to exclude one category out of it so that $9 product from that category can be bought.

Update 1:
Thank you so much for the help shadyyx

I tried shadyyx method but I am getting this error:
`unexpected T_BOOLEAN_OR` in this line

```
<?php if ($this->cart->getSubtotal() >= 10 || $this->cart->productsAreInCategory(1)) { ?>
```

Update 2: I tried this but it gave a pop up saying just error and ok button
`<?php if (($this->cart->getSubtotal() >= 10) || $this->cart->productsAreInCategory(1)) { ?>`

I tried this 
`<?php if (($this->cart->getSubtotal() >= 10) || ($this->cart->productsAreInCategory(1))) { ?>`
it did not give any error and does same work (min amount for all orders regardless of category id)

Comment: I don't think there's any shortcut method for that. You need to add an `elseif` condition in between to check whether the existing product's category is same as the category you want to exclude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go this way:

Extend the `system/library/cart.php` and add a method:

```php
public function productsAreInCategory($category_id) {
    $product_ids = array();
    foreach($this->getProducts() as $product) {
        $product_ids[] = $product['product_id'];
    }

    $categories = $this->db->query('SELECT category_id FROM ' . DB_PREFIX . 'product_to_category WHERE product_id IN (' . implode(',', $product_ids) . ')')->rows;

    $category_ids = array();
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $category_ids[] = $category['category_id'];
    }

    if(in_array($category_id, $category_ids) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

This method should accept a `$category_id` parameter to test against and should load categories for all products in cart. After first match a true is returned, if no match, a false is returned. You can now use this method this way:

```php
<?php if (($this->cart->getSubtotal() >= 10) || $this->cart->productsAreInCategory(1)) { ?>
<div id="payment"><?php echo $payment; ?></div>
<?php } else { ?>
<div class="warning">Minimum 10 Euro to checkout</div>
<?php }  ?>
```

Just replace the category ID in `$this->cart->productsAreInCategory(1)` with the correct one.

Comment: Thanks for the help
I am getting this error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_OR in

Comment: OK, and **in** where? Please, in the future provide us with whole error message... Edit Your question, add the error message for this solution and add also the part of the code where the error appears... Thanks.

Comment: OK, I may be blind or dumb but I do not see the problem there. Anyway try to put the first part of condition `$this->cart->getSubtotal() >= 10` into paranthesis, like this: `($this->cart->getSubtotal() >= 10)` - also check my edited answer...

Comment: @user3003829 I totally changed the method that was in `system/library/cart.php` - please update, try and let me know ;-) Now it should work fine (and should be little quicker).

Comment: yipee! you're my hero... it works... but if I add another product from another category and still lower than 10 it is not working (multiple products in same order)

Comment: Because You have the product from the allowed category in a cart...I thought due to the description that it is not possible to have in cart product from allowed category and another product and have the total less the $10... Or maybe I do not understand... How it is behaving and how do You want it to behave...?

Comment: It is behaving exactly I wanted... I want to keep it simple just like how it is now as the scenario I am referring would be a rare one I guess... Thank you so much for the help