# Opencart minimum order price

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I am trying to implement below code from here in catalogue/view/theme/default/template/checkout/confirm.tpl

```
<?php if ($this->cart->getSubtotal() >= 1000) { ?>
<div id="payment"><?php echo $payment; ?></div>
<?php } else { ?>
<div class="warning">Minimum 10 Euro to checkout</div>
<?php }  ?>
```

but i am getting an error

```
Notice: Undefined property: Loader::$cart in C:\xampp\htdocs\optest\catalog\view\theme\default\template\checkout\confirm.tpl on line 51
Fatal error: Call to a member function getSubtotal() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\optest\catalog\view\theme\default\template\checkout\confirm.tpl on line 51
```

**reference taken:**

[Opencart minimum order price exclude one category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20042912/opencart-minimum-order-price-exclude-one-category)

http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=53810

Comment: which version of opencart you are using? If it is above 2.0 then you wont be able to do so in your tpl file directly.

Comment: @VedPandya  yes its 2.0, then how to solve the issue

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not the same way but you can do it like this:

Add this line in your checkout.php controller file.

```
if ($this->cart->getSubtotal() < 1000) {
    $this->session->data['error'] = 'Your warning message';
    $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('checkout/cart'));
}
```

After

```
if ((!$this->cart->hasProducts() && empty($this->session->data['vouchers'])) || (!$this->cart->hasStock() && !$this->config->get('config_stock_checkout'))) {
    $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('checkout/cart'));
}
```

Thats it.

Comment: This is not working in my case it is not redirecting to cart back.

Comment: @HardikaSatasiya If the given solution does not work for you then ask a new question for that

Answer (score 0):

The code below is working for me:

```
    <?php if($this->session->data['currency'] == 'USD') : ?>
       <?php if($this->cart->getSubtotal() < 2enter code here0) : ?>
       <div class="warning"><center><?php echo $text_comandamin_eur; ?></center></div>
       <?php endif; ?>
    <?php } elseif($this->session->data['currency'] == 'INR') : ?>
       <?php if($this->cart->getSubtotal() < 1000) : ?>
       <div class="warning"><center><?php echo $text_comandamin_ron; ?></center></div>
       <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```