# opencart 1.5+ redirect error in minmum amount checkout

Tags: php, opencart

if somebody clicks on checkout, its should check the subtotal is greater than stotal or equal, if it satisfies the condition it should successfully redirect to checkout page or else it should redirect to cart page

i have added this code in catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php

**here is my code**

```
    $this->data['stotal'] = 1000;

if ($this->cart->getSubtotal() <= $this->data['stotal'] ){
$this->session->data['error'] = 'Minimum amout should be 1000 to checkout';
$this->redirect($this->url->link('checkout/cart'));

$this->data['checkout'] = false;
} else {
        $this->data['checkout'] = $this->url->link('checkout/checkout', '', 'SSL');

    }
```

**i am getting this error**

"The page isn't redirecting properly"

if i comment the redirect url, then it redirects to home page but the "Minimum amout should be 1000 to checkout" message stays for long time, it goes only after i click on close icon

**Note: i am trying this in 1.5+ not in 2.0**

Comment: Your question has not enough information to describe your problem like Where you are putting this code?

Comment: i have added this code in catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php

Comment: If  if condition satisfied then it will redirect to cart.php but it's already on cart.php so it's get in to the selfloop  and browser shows message 'The page isn't redirecting properly' .

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33146524/opencart-minimum-order-price